# Alternative ways to clear the tmp files & backup's from cPanel

Tags: cpanel

[image]

If we are running out of disk space, inorder to free up the disk space. 
Access to cPanel through browser is restricted. Durning shifts, system admin will not be available.

So I executed certain commands through shell access to clear tmp, and
different forms of backups such as differential, incremental, cumulative & full backup.

How would we execute the shell script commands needed to clear up all the junks either through programmatic or 
calling the shell script directly by triggering cron jobs that will be placed inside in the home directory.

In .htaccess file we are going to restrict accessing to such files by two or three IP addresses.

Is there any solution, in-order to trigger the shell script from the back-end side of admin web-page?

Comment: What kind of shell access?  SSH?  If that is the case you can create a passwordless ssh key pair, and push the public part to the server.  https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/  Then the SSH connection and script can be scripted from your local computer.